# Using Enum in java to store a fixed set of mutable objects

Tags: java, android, enums, mutable

I am creating an Android app that draws to the `canvas`. For this, I have defined rectangular screenareas that I want to draw to the canvas. As I am always drawing a fixed set of screenareas, I was thinking of using `Enum` (as `Enum` is designed for fixed sets).

Here is my `enum`:

```
public enum LayoutEnum {
    FULLSCREEN(
            new ScreenArea(
                new Rect(
                        0,
                        0,
                        MainActivity.getDevice().getWidth(),
                        MainActivity.getDevice().getHeight()),
                Attributes.BG_PAINT)),
    LOGO_AREA(
            new ScreenArea (
                    new Rect(
                            (int) (0.3 * FULLSCREEN.getScreenArea().getArea().width()),
                            (int) (0.3 * FULLSCREEN.getScreenArea().getArea().width()),
                            (int) (FULLSCREEN.getScreenArea().getArea().width() - 0.3 * FULLSCREEN.getScreenArea().getArea().width()),
                            (int) (0.7 * FULLSCREEN.getScreenArea().getArea().width())),
                    Attributes.BG_PAINT)
    );

    private ScreenArea screenArea;

    LayoutEnum(ScreenArea screenArea) {
        this.screenArea = screenArea;
    }

    public ScreenArea getScreenArea() {
        return screenArea;
    }
}
```

`ScreenArea` is a simple class that holds a `Rect` and a `Paint` and contains a `draw` method (and some getters and setters).

The question I have, is: **is this a good approach?**

On one hand I am working with a fixed set of variables. On the other hand, these variables are mutable and I can change their attributes (e.g., using the getters and setters). For example, I can call `FULLSCREEN.getScreenArea().getPaint().setColor(Color.BLUE)`

When you look at `Enum` it says it is

> a special data type that enables for a variable to be a set of
>   predefined constant

So I do have a fixed set, it is predefined, but not necessarily constant.

My original approach was to define a class called `Layout` which contained a `HashMap` of `Screenarea`'s. In that case, I was using e.g., `Layout.get("fullscreen").draw(canvas)` to draw the screenarea to the canvas. In this new approach I am using e.g., `FULLSCREEN.getScreenArea().draw(canvas)`.

One of the reasons I would like to switch is to introduce a typesafe solution. Of course, it would also be possible to switch from a `HashMap` to an `EnumMap` and store the names of my screenareas in an `Enum`.

Hope you can point me in the right direction: a direction that not only works (the above is already working) but is also acceptable and doesn't smell.

Comment: Would probably migrate to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but leaving open in case someone disagrees.

Comment: It's not a good solution. It's global state which is always bad. It looks like you're trying to reinvent dependency injection using enum constants. Just use Guice or Spring.

Comment: Settled for the `EnumMap`. Works like a charm and typesafe!